# Crontab configuration on CentOS

Tags: centos, cron

I have a Magento installation running on a VPS that runs on CentOS. I've been trying to implement a backup solution using the script found in here: https://github.com/zertrin. It worked fine and my next step was to automate it. Despite all my efforts the Cron job is not running. Here is what I have got in /etc/crontab:

```
* 20 * * * root echo "Cron Worked $(date)" >> /tmp/cronworked.txt
#
* 16 * * 1-6 root /root/duplicity-backup.sh -c /etc/duplicity-backup.conf -b
#
* 4 * * 7 root /root/duplicity-backup.sh -c /etc/duplicity-backup.conf -f
#
* 20 * * 7 root /root/duplicity-backup.sh -c /etc/duplicity-backup.conf -n
#
* 20 * * * root echo "Cron Worked $(date)" >> /tmp/cronworked3.txt
```

Both my test cron jobs (first one and the last one), work fine, but not those commands in the middle. They work fine if I issues them as standalone commands but for some reason not as Cron jobs.

Anyone can guide me to figure out what this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a couple of things you can check:

1. Make sure `/root/duplicity-backup.sh` is executable
2. If you have a local mail server configured, you should receive an email about the output of the cron jobs, which might tell you what's going wrong
3. If you don't receive emails from the cron job, then redirect stdout AND stderr to a file. That should help figuring out what's going wrong
4. Add `bash` in front of the script name to make sure it's running with `bash` and not something else, somehow, like this:

   ```
   * 4 * * 7 root bash /root/duplicity-backup.sh -c /etc/duplicity-backup.conf -f
   ```

Having the script output and error messages should help. If they don't please paste them here.

Comment: I tried all those without much luck. First it wasn't executable, so I made it executable and tried, but it didn't work. Then I added bash in front of it and it didn't work either. I don't know how to redirect stderr and stdout to a file so I did a bit of search and added this to cron job. '* 21 * * 1-6 root /root/duplicity-backup.sh -c /etc/duplicity-backup.conf -b >> /www/logs/crontab.shop.log 2>&1' but I can't see it generating a log file. I can copy the logs from the cron log file though. Just realised the log file location for stderr and stdout is wrong. Just corrected it.

Comment: I managed to get the errors to that log file and now it is 100% sure it is nothing to do with Cron. The message I'm getting is this, but not sure if it is an area where you can help me with:            'GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 40416B44
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
===== End GnuPG log ====='

Comment: Not sure if I can help you further as I'm not too familiar with GnuPG nor this backup tool. What I can say is that evidently something is different in the environment when you run the script in a shell and when it runs in cron. If I had to guess it's related to your gpg-agent. The secret key is loaded in the agent when you are in the shell, but not when you run this in cron, or in cron the agent is not accessible. Perhaps you need to set some environment variables when calling the script, like GPG_AGENT_INFO and GPG_TTY

Comment: No worries mate! At least I found out why it didn't run in the first place, thanks your support.